# Is it ok to use the "rel" attribute on images in order to pull in information to a jQuery image caption in XHTML 1.0

Tags: jquery, gallery

Just wondering if its a best practice to use the "rel" attribute on images in order to pull in information to a jQuery image caption in XHTML 1.0?

Its working in the browser (its an image slideshow), but using the snippet:

```
    <a href="molecules.html"> <img src="images/molecules.jpg" alt="Molecular Structure" width="680px" height="360"  title="#" rel="&lt;h3>Molecular Structure&lt;/h3>Molecular Structure." />
```

on each image throws errors in the validation due to escaping the characters with

```
    "&lt;h3".
```

Is there a more standards-compliant way of pulling in image caption text from the  tag other than via the "rel" attribute?

Do I need to encapsulate ALL jQuery with the CDATA tag ?

Thanks in advance, -querystring

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div id="side-info"> </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="gallery"> <a href="#"> <img src="http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab201/xenomorph313/img-1.jpg" alt="Molecules" width="680" height="360"  title="#" rel="Molecules." > </a> <a href="#"> <img src="http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab201/xenomorph313/img-2.jpg" alt="class" width="680" height="360" title="#" rel="Bricks." > </a> <a href="#"> <img src="http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab201/xenomorph313/img-3.jpg" alt="hexagons" width="680" height="360" title="#" rel="Hexagons." > </a> <a href="#"> <img src="http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab201/xenomorph313/img-4.jpg" alt="fractals" width="680" height="360" title="#" rel="Fractals." > </a> <a href="#"> <img src="http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab201/xenomorph313/img-5.jpg" alt="chrome" width="680" height="360" title="#" rel="Chrome." > </a> <a href="#"> <img src="http://i864.photobucket.com/albums/ab201/xenomorph313/img-6.jpg" alt="Joined Molecules" width="680" height="360" title="#" rel="Joined Molecules." > </a>
                <div class="caption">
                <div class="content"></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
```

Fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsinc/bkdf9q7j/7/)

Comment: Why not only passing text in the rel value ? 
And what about HTML5 data- attribute ?

Comment: Because, as it stands, the gallery is working, and my DTD is in XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: I don't think putting data&tags in a rel attribute is a good way to make valid XHTML

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer. Would putting the text in the title attribute be more appropriate?